# Print a number table in a simple format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am stuck trying to print out a table in Python which would look like this (first number stands for amount of numbers, second for amount of columns):

```
>>> print_table(13,4)
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13
```

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly more difficult than it sounds initially.

```
def numbers(n, r):
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, range(r*i, min(r*(i + 1), n + 1)))) for i in range(n//r + 1)))

numbers(13, 4)

#>>> 0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def numbers(a,b):

 i=0;
 c=0;
 while i<=a:
  print(i,end="") #prevents printing a new line
  c+=1
  if c>=b:
   print("\n") #prints a new line when the number of columns is reached and then reset the current column number
   c=0;
```

I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
def num2(n=10, r=3):
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(tuple(map(str, range(n+1)))[i:i+r]) for i in range(0, n+1, r)))

<<<
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10
```